# Comprehension and Impredicativity

Tags: logic, set-theory

Wang and McNaughton (*Les Systemes Axiomatiques de la Theorie des Ensembles*, 1953) discuss briefly the topic of *impredicativity* in chapter 2 (titled 'Type Theory') of the above mentioned book, but I'm having difficulty understanding what's going on with a particular example, to which I'll turn immediately after giving you the necessary context.

The context is that of an axiomatic theory T of types, which has three axioms:

1. $\forall x_i (x_i \in y_{y+1} \leftrightarrow x_i \in z_{i+1}) \rightarrow y_{i+1} = z_{i+1}; \tag{Extensionality}$
2. Given $\varphi(x_i)$ s.t. $y_{i+1}$ is not among the free variables of $\varphi$, $$\exists y_{i+1} : \forall x_i(x_i \in y_{i+1} \leftrightarrow \varphi(x_i)) \tag{Comprehension};$$
3. A long formula to the effect that there are infinitely many individuals. $\tag{Infinity}$

Toward the very end of that chapter they consider class $w_3$, and claim that this:

$$\forall x_1 : x_i \in y_2 \leftrightarrow \exists z_2(x_1 \in z_2 \land z_2 \in w_3) \tag{4}$$

follows from the axiom of comprehension. If we let

$$\varphi(x_i) := (x_i \in z_{i+1} \land z_{i+1} \in w_3) \tag{5}$$

then it seems that (4) follows from (2). But the definition of comprehension doesn't apply to (4) because (5) defines $\varphi$ in a way that a term of higher-type (viz. $z_{i+1}$) is among the free variables of $\varphi$.

I'm asking, basically, about the legitimacy of the move from axiom (2) to (4) via (5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot browse Wang & McNaughton' booklet; thus I'll refer to Hao Wang, [A Survey of Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GC9E0E) (1963), *Ch.XVI : DIFFERENT AXIOM SYSTEMS*.

See page 406, for an exposition of a "simplified" type theory, following Gödel's 1931 paper.

The "general" restriction is that :

> the predicate $\in$ occurs only in contexts of the form $x_n \in y_{i+1}, n = 1, 2, \ldots$.

The restriction on the [axiom of comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) :

> $∃y_{i+1} ∀x_i (x_i \in y_{i+1} ↔ \varphi(x_i))$

is the "standard" one, common also to $\mathsf {ZFC}$, i.e. that $y_{i+1}$ does not occur in $\varphi$.

Thus, the intsance of the formula :

> $\varphi(x_i) := \exists z_{i+1} (x_i \in z_{i+1} ∧ z_{i+1} \in w_{i+2})$

used in (4) is :

> $\exists z_2 (x_1 \in z_2 ∧ z_2 \in w_3)$

which is *well-formed*.

When we apply *Comprehension* to get :

> > $∀x_1(x_1 \in y_2 ↔ \exists z_2 (x_1 \in z_2 ∧ z_2 \in w_3)$

we have no occurrence of $y_2$ in $\varphi$, which is $\varphi(x_1, w_3)$ ($z_2$ is bound).

The *axiom schema of comprehension* (or *specification*) allows for *parameters*, i.e. free variables $w_i$, different from the $y$.

Comment: Well, in TST "stratification" is not just syntactic, but semantic. Type theory's restriction is stronger than just stratification.